# Finding the point corresponding to an arc length on the ellipse iteratively

Tags: c#

Given a distance (arc length) anticlockwise away from a known point (`P_0`) on an ellipse, I am trying to find the point at that distance (`P_1`).

Since I cannot evaluate the `t` corresponding to a specific arc length analytically, I am forced to iterate through each discrete point until I arrive at an answer.

My initial code is something like this:

```
// t_0 is the parametric t on the ellipse corresponding to P_0

Point GetPos(double distance, double t_0, double res = 5000, double epsilon = 0.1)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < res; ++i)
    {
        // The minus is to make the point move in an clockwise direction
        t = t_0 - (double)(i)/(double)res * t_0;
        // Find the integral from t to t_0 to get the arc length
        // If arc length is within epsilon, return the corresponding point
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this code may not converge if the arc length given by the `t` value just nicely overshoots the epsilon value. And since this is a loop that decreases t, the overshoot will not be corrected.

I was thinking of modelling this as a control problem, using something like a PID controller. However, I realised that since the set point (which is my desired arc length), and my output (which is essentially the parametric `t`), are referring to different variables, I do not know how to proceed.

Is there a better method of solving this kind of problem or am I missing something from my current approach?

Comment: first - yes you are right (there is much on this here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/433094/how-to-determine-the-arc-length-of-ellipse) - now the question is: how much to you now on nummeric integration?

Comment: matlab can solve problems like this nicely.  You can generate a dll from matlab that can be call by c#.  matlab can return nice jpg plot of solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some thought I used a binary search method instead, since a PID controller is difficult to tune and usually does not converge fast enough for all cases of the ellipses under consideration.

```
double max = t_0; double min = 0; double result = 0; double mid = 0;

mid = (max - min) / 2.0;
while ((Math.Abs(distance - result) > epsilon))
{
    result = // Arc Length from t_0 to mid
    if (result > distance) 
    {
        min = mid;
        mid = ((max - mid) / 2.0) + min;
    }
    else
    {
        max = mid;
        mid = (mid - min) / 2.0;
    }
}

// Return the point at t = max
```

The binary search works as the search is always over an ordered range (from `t_0` to 0).